# knitr: generating summary tables with tabs in the loop?

Tags: r, tabs, r-markdown, knitr

I was trying to do the following using [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36458193/knitr-one-plot-per-tabset-in-for-loop) , but i want to autogenerate the tab with summary table of lm()
I created first the list with all summary tables: `list_lm`

````
---
title: 
author: 
date: 
output:
    html_document
---

# {.tabset}
```{r}
list_lm=list()
for(i in 1:10){
  list_lm[[i]]=  lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars)
}
```


```{r,results='asis', echo=FALSE}
for(i in 1:10){
  cat('##',i,' \n')
  print(list_lm[[i]] )
}
```
````

but it does not seem to produce a nice output when I do print(list_lm[[i]] )

[image: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342162/regression-tables-in-markdown-format-for-flexible-use-in-r-markdown-v2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `knitr::kable` to better format the output:

````
---
output:
  html_document
---
  
# {.tabset}
```{r}
list_lm=list()
for(i in 1:10){
  list_lm[[i]]=  lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars)
}
```


```{r,results='asis', echo=FALSE}
for(i in 1:10){
  cat('##',i,' \n')
  cat("Coefficients: \n")
  print(knitr::kable(list_lm[[i]]$coefficients)) 
  cat("\n")
  cat("Summary: \n")
  s <- summary(list_lm[[i]])
  print(knitr::kable(data.frame(sigma = s$sigma,r.squared=s$r.squared)) )
  cat('\n')
}
```
````

[image]

Another option is to use [`broom`package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom.html) :

````
---
output:
  html_document
---

`r knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, cache = F)`
  
# {.tabset}
```{r, ECHO = F, MESSAGE = F}
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
list_lm=list()
for(i in 1:10){
  list_lm[[i]]=  lm(dist ~ speed, data=cars)
}
```


```{r,results='asis', echo=FALSE}

for(i in 1:10){
  cat('##',i,' \n')
  list_lm[[i]] %>% tidy() %>% knitr::kable() %>% print
  cat('\n')
}
```
````

[image]

Comment: But then i will loose all ither info from the model like adj R^2 , significance tests , F statistics and etc

Comment: Sorry, I tried to use very simple model for example, but my actual model have continuous and categorical predictors

Comment: You should decide which info you want to display about the model an then generate the output of you choice, see my edit.

Comment: Thanks! So it is not possible to print raw output? I was looking into pander() or xtable() function, but I could not make it work

Comment: to use xtable, output should be pdf_document, not html_document

Comment: See my edit with the broom package which could better fit to your needs